# SQL alias and count

Tags: mysql

So I have the following chunck:

```
SELECT name AS Author
FROM articles,
SELECT Author, count(Author)
from articles
group by Author;
```

I want it to have articles grouped by name, aliased as Author. However, I get the following error:

> "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SELECT name, count(name) from articles group by
>   name LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 3"

How would I go about fixing the syntax?

Comment: Did you solve this? You cannot have another select statement, after the from clause the way you are attempting,

Comment: Also if you are using just one column, it's better to reference the column name, rather than the alias in the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name AS Author, count(name)
FROM articles
group by name